# How to store/save data in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How to ***store/save data in react native***.*Like we use shared-preference in android, is there any solution for react native.I am new to react-nactive.*

> please add sample example

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use React Native [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/) for storing data to local storage of the device.

```js
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Use this to save data

```js
    AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

AsyncStorage accepts value as only **string**, so you may need to use `JSON.stringify()` before setting the value to AsyncStorage

And to retrieve data use

```js
    AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
```

Example Code :

```js
    const KEY = 'USER_DATA'
    
    let value = { name: yogi }

    AsyncStorage.setItem(KEY, value);

    AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY).then(asyncStorageRes => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(asyncStorageRes))
    });
```

For sensitive data such as access tokens, payment information, etc. you may wish to use [EncryptedStorage](https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage)

```js
    import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';
```

It uses a similar API to AsyncStorage so you can use the following to save and retrieve data:

```js
    EncryptedStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
    EncryptedStorage.getItem('key');
```

There are of course [other storage options](https://reactnative.directory/?search=storage) to choose from too.

Comment: Please add sample code...Its easy to me to learn faster.Thank you.

Comment: Any issues with AsyncStorage?

Comment: Yup problem with the numbers

Comment: You mean you cant store numbers? You need to convert your data to string before setting the value. Its always better to use native modules than 3rd party modules.

Comment: I believe in that too but the numbers i saved is like 23_34-44jdj_njdnd and its gives object of each numbers

Comment: you used JSON.stringfy() ? How are you converting the numbers?

Comment: Being tied to RN 0.52 (using expo), `AnyStorage.setItem()` does not resolve. Any alternative suggestions for storing simple settings on both android and iOS?

Comment: Deprecated. Use @react-native-async-storage/async-storage instead. https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Comment: This will be removed from react-native core in future. But can be used with @react-native-async-storage/async-storage . You can install with npm  ```npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage```

Answer (score 4):

React Native also have shared preferences this is npm command to get it: `npm install react-native-shared-preferences --save`. You can get complete details(how to set it up in react project) here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences

Comment: Please add sample code...Its easy to me to learn faster.Thank you.

Comment: Everything is there in link, how to import, set, get and delete.

Answer (score 1):

used Async storage class to stored and retrive data in react native

Answer (score -1):

you can use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) that is easier to use than async storage.
this library is great that uses async storage to save data asynchronously and uses memory to load and save data instantly synchronously, so we save data async to memory and use in app sync, so this is great.

```
export const RNStorage = {// RNStorage : custom data store object
     token: undefined, // string type
     isShow: undefined, // bool type
     userInfo: undefined, // object type
};


import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, () => {
    ... // RNStorage 【Property access code snippet】
});

// OR ---------------------------------------------------------------

const result = await XStorage.initStorageSync(RNStorage, AsyncStorage);
if (result) {
    ... // RNStorage 【Property access code snippet】
}


// RNStorage 【Property access code snippet】
// From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously

console.log(RNStorage.isShow);
// equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))] 

RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==';
// equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]  

RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30};
// equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
```